# Jquery get tr value

Tags: jquery

in below code I want to get the values from a specified  in jquery.means I want to get the value of tr class=2 how can I achive this?

```
<div class="fav">
    <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class=1">
    <td>........
    </td>
    >/tr>
    <tr class=2>
    <td>......</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="3">
    <td>........
    </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
```

Comment: Did you try anything for this?If yes ,Show the code you used

Comment: yes wait I will show you

Answer (score 1):

If you want html of row, then try this, You should you **meaningful name** for class and should be alpha numeric if not aphabetical.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jWjx/1/)**

```
$('tr.2').html()
```

You have many errors in html of not closing the class attributes in quotes and using angle bracket of `tr`. check the corrected `html`.

```
<div class="fav">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="1">
                <td>........</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="2">
                <td>...tr with class 2...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="3">
                <td>........</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of selectors you could use, but I would use something like:

```
$("div.fav").find("tr.2")
```

However, the code you posted is missing some quotes around some of the class names which would stop it working:

```
<div class="fav">
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="1">
<td>........
</td>
>/tr>
<tr class="2">
<td>......</td>
</tr>
<tr class="3">
<td>........
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: But sir the tr class is not static its coming dynamically..

Comment: then how I get the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var class_name="3"; //you can specify the class name here

 var x=$("div.fav").find("tr."+class_name+" td").html();
 alert(x);

});
```

Get

```
      ........
```

Comment: But the tr class is not static its coming dynamically.

Comment: @user2318361  Can you explane your requirement?When you need to find the value? On page load or on button click,Please specify

Comment: @user2318361,I ahve edited my answer,Now you can assign values dynamicaly to var  class_name